# Grep and print only beginning and end of a string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a list of strings, they are product codes followed by product description and the price. I would like to `Grep` and print only the product codes and the prices. Product codes are combinations of capital letters and digits and the prices are digits and a comma as a decimal mark. Codes, descriptions and prices are separated with a space, like:

```
AA1AA This is an example for free 0,00
BE661N For your 0,02
```

and the output would be:

```
AA1AA 0,00
BE661N 0,02
```

I have tried several regexps in combination with `-o` and `-v` switches but failed miserably. As always, `Awk` solution is also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{print $1, $NF}' file
AA1AA 0,00
BE661N 0,02
```

[`$1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fields) is first field and [`$NF`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-NF-variable-1) is last field in each record.

Comment: First Awk solution in 23 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Through sed.

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]].*[[:blank:]]/ /' file
```

`[[:blank:]].*[[:blank:]]` would match all the characters from the first blank space upto the last blank space. Replacing all the matched chars with space will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

**GREP**

I add a solution using `grep` (Note: It is better to use `awk` or `sed`, it's just out of curiosity)

```
grep -E -o "^\S+\b" file | paste - <(grep -E -o "\b\S+$" file)
```

you get:

```
AA1AA   0,00
BE661N  0,02
```

**BASH**

Also, I added a solution using pure `bash` and [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
while read line; do 
  echo "${line/%\ */} ${line##* }";
done < file
```